# not getting getText() option in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

[enter image description here][1]

Hello everyone I am not getting this option .get Text() when I write it is showing wrong in android studio please help help
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF227.png

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Emailbox` is of type View:

```
private View Emailbox;
```

The [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) class in Android, doesn't have any `getText()` methods, hence that error. So most likely your field should be defined of type [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText):

private EditText Emailbox;

As the other fields are, and **not** as a View.

P.S. All elements in Android are views, meaning that each class extends the View class.

Comment: then what have to do to now Actually this is my first project that's why i am getting the problem. Can elaborate more or can you give me th right code so that  my problem can get fixed

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image. However, simply modifying `private View Emailbox;` to `private EditText Emailbox;`, will solve the issue. Have you even try it?

Comment: when i run the application error like this =error: variable Emailbox might not have been initialized
                email= Emailbox.getText().toString() ;

Comment: As I understand, you just solved the first problem, right? And this is another issue that is derived from the initial question, correct?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: how to fix that problem??

Comment: In general, other questions that derive from the initial question should be considered new questions. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: yeah okk i will ask a new problem can i provide my file of app so that you can check and help me to fix my problem bcz i don't have much time bcz i have to give this app to another person.

Comment: So, add the content of the file to your **new** question, and I'll take a look. In the meanwhile, take a moment and accept my answer, as you say, it already solved the first issue.

Comment: It is showing you have reach your limit of question

Comment: if you can provide your email i will mail you the file of my app

Comment: I can only answer here, on Stackoverflow. If it requires to wait, then you should wait until it's possible to post another question. You can leave here the link.

Comment: okk i am adding my file in google drive from there you can download is it okk???

Comment: No, you should add the code as text in a new question, not a link to external resources.

Comment: You're very welcome, krishna.

Comment: brr are you on quora or rediit here i am asking question and my question is getting closed

Answer (score 0):

You can use EditText instead of View.
To get text programmatically using getText() method

Comment: How to do that can you please this is my first project that's why i am getting problem

Comment: can you please say how to do that this is my first project in android studio

Comment: As you have taken the object of EditText namebox and passwordbox .
Do same for email as well as in xml